# Past Exam paper on obtaining a differental equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be solutions of the differential equation
                            $$y′′+ p(x)y′+q(x)y = 0$$
where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continuous on an open interval $I$.

Write down the equations that $y_1$ and $y_2$ satisfy and use these to obtain the following equation

$$y_1y_2′′−y_2y_1′′+ p(x)(y_1y_2′−y_2y_1′) = 0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have the solutions given, i.e. y1 and y2 both satisfy the differential equation itself so actually substituting this into the ODE and rearranging will give you answer you need.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $y_1$ and $y_2$ both satisfy the differential equation itself. Write out these out and see if you can maybe manipulate them to get what you're after.

By the way I hope your Linear algebra/programming exam went well today you should really take a bit of a break to recover your mind. You had a three hour exam just so maybe it's not the best time to be trying to solve this problem.

Comment: It did go well thank you for asking (LP was a lot better than LA, and I actually had 3hrs 45mins due to extra time). The only way you could've known about that is if you know which university this paper is from, but if you knew that then you'd also know that the AC/DE 40 credit paper is on Tuesday, so unfortunately no time to waist - oh mysterious incog121 who art thou.